# Jammit Warning when deploying Locomotive CMS on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, jammit, locomotivecms

I am trying to deploy locomotive CMS on heroku according to their installation guide http://www.locomotivecms.com/support/installation/heroku. I uploaded the assets to an S3 bucket. So, on localhost it works fine, but when visiting the site on heroku an error message gets displayed:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.  If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I checked the heroku logs:

```
    2011-05-23T11:12:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 29674 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
    2011-05-23T11:12:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Jammit Warning: Asset compression disabled -- Java unavailable.
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/../lib/mongo/connection.rb:518:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/../lib/mongo/connection.rb:656:in `setup'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/../lib/mongo/connection.rb:101:in `initialize'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/../lib/mongo/connection.rb:152:in `new'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/../lib/mongo/connection.rb:152:in `from_uri'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/config/database.rb:86:in `master'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/config/database.rb:19:in `configure'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:319:in `configure_databases'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:114:in `from_hash'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from (eval):2:in `send'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from (eval):2:in `from_hash'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:66
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3
    2011-05-23T11:12:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2011-05-23T04:12:35-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2011-05-23T11:12:35+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET morning-night-832.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
    2011-05-23T04:12:36-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 80.218.114.86 | 795 | http | 503
    2011-05-23T11:12:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET morning-night-832.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
    2011-05-23T11:12:39+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET morning-night-832.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
    2011-05-23T11:30:06+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET morning-night-832.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
```

As it seems, there is a problem with jammit and the assets.

```
        2011-05-23T11:12:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Jammit Warning: Asset compression disabled -- Java unavailable.
```

I didn't found any useful hints on Google until now. Any ideas how to solve that?

Update: I adapted the mongoid.yml but get still the same error message described as above. I checked again the logs:

```
    2011-05-23T12:02:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 41882 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
    2011-05-23T12:03:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Jammit Warning: Asset compression disabled -- Java unavailable.
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 401 Unauthorized (RestClient::Request::Unauthorized)
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:220:in `process_result'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:169:in `transmit'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:166:in `transmit'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:60:in `execute'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:31:in `execute'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/resource.rb:54:in `get'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/client.rb:540:in `send'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/client.rb:540:in `process'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/client.rb:522:in `get'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/client.rb:113:in `list_domains'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/locomotive/hosting/heroku.rb:41:in `enable_heroku'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/initializers/../../lib/locomotive.rb:89:in `configure_hosting'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/initializers/../../lib/locomotive.rb:57:in `after_configure'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/initializers/../../lib/locomotive.rb:47:in `configure'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/initializers/locomotive.rb:3
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:201
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:200
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2011-05-23T05:03:03-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 80.218.114.86 | 795 | http | 503
```

I suppose this time the following line is the problem:

```
    2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 401 Unauthorized (RestClient::Request::Unauthorized)
```

I supppose I need to configure again my heroku login and password. Let's try that...

Update 2: still doesn't work. Below my mongoid.yml config

```
    defaults: &defaults
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      # slaves:
      #   - host: slave1.local
      #     port: 27018
      #   - host: slave2.local
      #     port: 27019

    development:
      <<: *defaults
      database: locomotive_dev

    test:
      <<: *defaults
      database: locomotive_test

    # set these environment variables on your prod server
    production:
      # <<: *defaults
      # database: locomotive_prod

      # other settings for production
      # host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
      # port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
      # username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
      # password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
      # database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>

      #heroku
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>

      # bushido (mongohq_url will also work)
      # uri: <%= ENV['MONGODB_URL'] %>
```

My settings in config/initializers/locomotive.rb

```
    require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../lib/locomotive.rb'

    Locomotive.configure do |config|

      # A single locomotive instance can serve one single site or many.
      # If you want to run many different websites, you will have to specify
      # your own domain name (ex: locomotivehosting.com).
      #
      # Ex:
      # config.multi_sites do |multi_sites|
      #   # each new website you add will have a default entry based on a subdomain
      #   # and the multi_site_domain value (ex: website_1.locomotivehosting.com).
      #   multi_sites.domain = 'example.com' #'myhostingplatform.com'
      #
      #   # define the reserved subdomains
      #   # Ex:
      #   multi_sites.reserved_subdomains = %w(www admin email blog webmail mail support help site sites)
      # end
      config.multi_sites = false

      # configure the hosting target for the production environment. Locomotive can be installed in:
      # - your own server
      # - Heroku (you need to create an account in this case)
      # - Bushi.do (see the bushi.do website for more explanations)
      #
      # the possible options are: server, heroku, bushido or auto (default)
      # if you select 'auto', Locomotive will look after specific ENV variables to check
      # the matching platform (Heroku and Bushido set their own ENV variables).
      #
      config.hosting = :auto

      # In case you host Locomotive in Heroku, the engine uses the heroku api to add / remove domains.
      # there are 2 ways of passing heroku credentials to Locomotive
      #   - from ENV variables: HEROKU_LOGIN & HEROKU_PASSWORD
      #   - from this file, see the example below and uncomment it if needed
      config.heroku = {
        :login      => ENV['HEROKU_LOGIN'],
        :password   => ENV['HEROKU_PASSWORD']
      }

      # Locomotive uses the DelayedJob gem for the site import module.
      # In case you want to deploy to Heroku, you will have to pay for an extra dyno.
      # If you do not mind about importing theme without DelayedJob, disable it.
      #
      # Warning: this option is not used if you deploy on bushi.do and we set automatically the value to true.
      config.delayed_job = false

      # configure how many items we display in sub menu in the "Contents" section.
      # config.lastest_items_nb = 5

      # default locale (for now, only en, de, fr, pt-BR and it are supported)
      config.default_locale = :en

      # tell if logs are enabled. Useful for debug purpose.
      config.enable_logs = true

      # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in the DeviseMailer, NotificationMailer, ...etc
      # if you do not put the domain name in the email, Locomotive will take the default domain name depending
      # on your deployment target (server, Heroku, Bushido, ...etc)
      #
      # Ex:
      # config.mailer_sender = 'support'
      # # => 'support@heroku.com' (Heroku), 'support@bushi.do' (Bushido), 'support@example.com' (Dev) or 'support@<your_hosting_platform>' (Multi-sites)
      config.mailer_sender = 'support'
    end unless Locomotive.engine? || Rails.env.test?
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the config/initializers/locomotive.rb file

Comment: Updated my answer again.. could not type the commands in the comment section :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jammit warning is not the problem in your case. If you switch off asset compression at runtime, this warning should go off..

I think there is some problem with your MongoDB connection params. Either you have not installed the MongoDB add-on or the connection params are incorrect.

By default, the heroku environment variables that you have specified in locomotive.rb are not defined. Either specify the username/password directly or from inside of your rails folder, use the following commands

```
heroku config:add HEROKU_LOGIN=<your_heroku_login>
heroku config:add HEROKU_PASSWORD=<your_heroku_password>
```

to add these env variables..

Comment: I tested whether I installed the mongohq add-on but it was already installed

Comment: I just found out that in mongoid.yml, the   uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %> was not uncommented. Changed that, let's see.

Comment: Also, if you are using mongomapper, check the initializer code as well.

Comment: Anyhow. Still receive the error message. As noted in my updated of the question above, the logs show the following error: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 401 Unauthorized (RestClient::Request::Unauthorized)

Comment: I check it, my Locomotive CMS runs with mongoid instead of mongomapper:

"Now, our goal is to port our prototype to Rails 3 and migrate from mongomapper to mongoid." (source: README.textile on https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine)

(I also have a mongoid.yml file in the app)

Comment: Pls check if you specified the heroku credentials correctly in config/initializers/locomotive.rb

Comment: Settings:

    config.heroku = {
      :login      => ENV['HEROKU_LOGIN'],
      :password   => ENV['HEROKU_PASSWORD']
    }

(see complete locomotive.rb file in question, 'update 2')

Comment: It works now. Summarzing, the following points needed to be changed

1. I need to uncomment the heroku config in mongoid.yml:

mongoid.yml, the uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>

2. I found out that yml files don't accept single quotes for variables/constants, I needed to set the heroku credentials between double quotes:

before: config.heroku = { :login => ENV['HEROKU_LOGIN'], :password => ENV['HEROKU_PASSWORD'] }

after: config.heroku = { :login => ENV["HEROKU_LOGIN"], :password => ENV["HEROKU_PASSWORD"] }


Thanks to all for the support!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you should be running ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.2 in order to make locomotive work.

Have you updated your ruby gem to thoe ?

```
2011-05-23T12:03:01+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 401 Unauthorized (RestClient::Request::Unauthorized)
```

If not, let's try Rvm : https://rvm.io

And reinstall your Locomotive setup and  then it should work !

If you need more details check the first tutorial about Rail installation :
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/